# Is there a project that aims to implement (part of) the Android APIs on a desktop JVM?

Tags: android, jvm

I am currently pondering the feasability of implementing part of the Android APIs on a desktop JVM and I was wondering whether you had already heard of such a project.

If there aren't, and you know good reasons why (beyond "no one has begun that yet"), I would be glad to read them.

Comment: Did you go anywhere with this? IcedRobot seems to be dead as of date.

Comment: @HRJ: Nah, I did not. It is probably pretty unrealistic to hope to do that, and not very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another project (apparently in its infancy) to bring the Android API on Linux Desktop.  It is called [**`IcedRobot`**](http://www.icedrobot.org/).  On the project's home page, it states its goals as:

> 1. Have Dalvik completely separated from the usual Android infrastructure
>      so that it runs as any other *unix
>      program in the Linux environment (and
>      non Linux, I personally want it to
>      work on OSX and QNX).
> 2. Avoid Dalvik and Harmony as much as possible and put the Android stack on
>      top of the OpenJDK class library, and
>      run the whole thing in Hotspot (this
>      is cool, ins’t it?).

Some related resources:

- [The GNUlization of Android](http://www.icedrobot.org/downloads/fosdem11/icedrobot-fosdem-2011-02-05.pdf) (PDF of FOSDEM presentation)
- [IcedRobot Dev mailing list](http://icedtea.classpath.org/mailman/listinfo/icedrobot-dev)
- [Running HelloAndroid](http://rkennke.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/icedrobotdaneel-awesomeness/)
- [The False Dawn of IcedRobot](http://www.danablankenhorn.com/2011/02/the-false-dawn-of-icedrobot.html)
- [FOSDEM: Icing the robot](http://lwn.net/Articles/427439/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain I understand your goal, but I'll assume you do not want to emulate ARM execution and therefore not run the whole Android stack, but instead implement some subset of the Android Java APIs running on standard JVM running standard Java byte code right?  If so, I do not know of any similar projects.

However, if you'd like to run the full Android stack (including Dalvik VM) on an arbitrary desktop machine (without emulation), take a look at the [**`android-x86.org`**](http://www.android-x86.org/) project.  There are [instructions](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/installhowto) for running a complete Android image within a virtual machine so that you could host Android applications within the same box.

[image: Android desktop screen]

There is also a project supplying a [LiveAndroid CD image](http://code.google.com/p/live-android/) suitable for running in *VirtualBox*, *VMWare* or *Microsoft Virtual PC* which may expedite proof of concept.

Hope that helps.